# HDMI w/ sound on Eyefinity?

Tags: hdmi, eyefinity

With the 5xxx series of the ATI Radeons, if I want Eyefinity set up, WITH sound through the HDMI, do I need extra adapters? Or is there some sort of Active Mini-Display Port to HDMI with a sound input? Or will it "just work"?